# In Python 3 on Windows, how can I set NTFS compression on a file? Nothing I've googled has gotten me even close to an answer

Tags: python, file, attributes, compression, ntfs

(Background: On an NTFS partition, files and/or folders can be set to "compressed", like it's a file attribute. They'll show up in blue in Windows Explorer, and will take up less disk space than they normally would. They can be accessed by any program normally, compression/decompression is handled transparently by the OS - this is *not* a .zip file. In Windows, setting a file to compressed can be done from a command line with the "Compact" command.)
[image: NTFS Compression Enabled]

Let's say I've created a file called "testfile.txt", put some data in it, and closed it. Now, I want to set it to be NTFS compressed. Yes, I could shell out and run Compact, but is there a way to do it directly in Python code instead?

Comment: http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32file__DeviceIoControl_meth.html ? You'll also need to read up on the corresponding WinAPI docs...

Comment: Wow, that's hardcore, but it might come down to that. I'm surprised - have I finally come across something that not in a readily available Python module? I'm still new to Python, but that would be a first for me! :-)

Comment: It seems like a bit of a niche problem. There might be some library that wraps this functionality... what I mentioned was just a result of  quick search on how to actually achieve what you're asking for. I'm on the road until the end of this week... | If you haven't figured it out before then, let me know, and i'll try to play with it and let you know of the outcome (but given the recent actions of the corporation running this site, I'm not likely to write it up as a proper answer).

Comment: This seems to work here: https://pastebin.com/bsZxuCby | Having the file open for both reading and writing seems important. Sorry I didn't have this sooner, I was traveling until last night.

Comment: Is this issue resolved? Can someone help me with this

Comment: @siddharthtaunk: I just added the answer to this, see below. Sorry about the delay. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I ended up cheating a bit and simply shelling out to the command line Compact utility. Here is the function I ended up writing. Errors are ignored, and it returns the output text from the Compact command, if any.

```
def ntfscompress(filename):

    import subprocess

    _compactcommand = 'Compact.exe /C /I /A "{}"'.format(filename)

    try:
        _result = subprocess.run(_compactcommand, timeout=86400,
                                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                 stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,text=True)
        return(_result.stdout)
    except:
        return('')
```